# Cannot resolve Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Tags: r, ggplot2, continuous, discrete

I've looked at some of the popular threads on this error but none seem to help me with mine.

I'm working with data, trying to create a line graph with dates on the x and lines representing three variables, Attendance (int), Registrants (int), and No.Show (int). I tried as.numeric but that didn't seem to do anything.

Here is my code:

```
IHS %>%
  filter(Start.Date != "2020-11-13", Start.Date != "2021-01-08", Start.Date != "2021-01-15", Start.Date != "2021-05-07") %>% 
  filter(Template != "Campus Event - IHS Tour (VIRTUAL)") %>%
ggplot(aes(x = Start.Date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Registrants, color = "Registrants")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = Attendance, color = "Attendance")) +
  geom_line(aes(y = No.Show, color = "No.Show")) +
  theme_classic() +
  annotate("rect", xmin = as.Date("2020-11-20"), xmax = as.Date("2021-01-22"), ymin = 0, ymax = 14,
  alpha = .09) + 
  annotate("text", x = as.Date("2020-11-20"), y = 12, label = "No tours\nduring holiday", hjust = -1, vjust = 0.5, size = 3) +
  annotate("text", x = as.Date("2021-04-09"), y = 26, label = "26", hjust = .5, vjust = -.9, size = 3) +
  annotate("text", x = as.Date("2021-04-09"), y = 15, label = "15", hjust = .5, vjust = -.9, size = 3) +
  annotate("text", x = as.Date("2021-04-09"), y = 11, label = "11", hjust = .5, vjust = -.9, size = 3) +
  labs(x = "Date", y = "Count")+
  ggtitle("IHS Tour Registrants, Attendance, and No Show") +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = as.Date(c("2020-09-11","2021-04-30")), breaks = as.Date(c("2020-09-11", "2020-09-18", "2020-09-25", "2020-10-02", "2020-10-02", "2020-10-11", "2020-10-16", "2020-10-23", "2020-10-30", "2020-11-06", "2020-11-06", "2020-11-20", "2020-11-06", "2021-01-22", "2021-01-29", "2021-02-05", "2021-02-12",  "2021-02-26", "2021-03-05", "2021-03-12", "2021-03-19", "2021-03-26", "2021-04-09",  "2021-04-16", "2021-04-23", "2021-04-30", "2021-04-30"))) +
  scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("#FF8000", "#7A1F2E", "#006699")) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,27), breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18,19,20,21,
                                  22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27)) +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, vjust = .5)) +
    theme(legend.position = "top") +
  theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size=10, face = "bold"),
        axis.text.x  = element_text(size=10, angle = 90), 
        axis.text.y = element_text(angle = 0, size = 9), 
        axis.title.y = element_text(angle=0, size = 10, vjust = .5, face = "bold"))
```

I know there's a lot going on, I can condense it if that's easier, but I figure since I can't really seem to pinpoint what's going wrong that the whole chunk of code would be good.

The graph was fine at one point, and I was able to produce this:
[image: graph]

But then when I tried rerunning the code the graph started to give me the error about discrete value supplied to a continuous scale.

Comment: Why are you using `scale_x_continuous` and not `scale_x_date`? Have you ensured that `Start.Date` is of class "Date"  and that your count variables are numeric? Check `str(IHS)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I use scale_x_date I get an error: Error: Invalid input: date_trans works with objects of class Date only

I've used as.Date(IHS$Start.Date, format = "%m/%d/%Y")

@Roland

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).